# Best practice for Angular 2 in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to rewrite my app in Angular 2 typescript and would like to use best practices. I've found the following [guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html) but it doesn't answer my very basic questions. Here is two questions:

1. In Components, is it ok to declare a local variable inside a function or should I declare it as private, right above the constructor?
2. How should I call variables inside nested functions? For example:

   ```
   replicator(){// return observable}
   myFunction(){// Nested function to be called}

   ngOnInit() {
       this.replicator().subscribe(function (data) {
           // Call function here
       }
   }
   ```

   Should I call my function by doing: `let self = this` before `this.replicator()` and then call `self.myFunction()`? Or is there a better way to do this?

PS If you have a good best practice guide, please post it as a comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How should I call variables inside nested functions

Use an arrow function ([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)).

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.replicator().subscribe((data) => {
        // Call function here
        this.somefunction
    }
}
```

> is it ok to declare a local variable inside a function or should I declare it as private, right above the constructor

Both are fine. Local if its only local to the function or `private` if other functions might need it

Comment: thanks! One more thing, how do you declare local variables? `myVar: string;` or `let myVar;`

Comment: `let myVar:string` or even better `const myVar = "some stringt"` if you know the value upfront and don't want it changed 

Comment: Alway declare your variables on top, type them and **initialise** them, it is also a good JavaScript practice because you avoid undefined values (doesn't help when you debug);
Typically, it looks like this: `let myVar: string = ''`. A null value would not help you to concatenate.